# Window alert from cypress test interface instead of window

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm testing JS Fiddle files from online documentation exemples, and I have set some window.alert() on the fiddles.
What I was expecting to have are simple window.Alert() that I can close with this :

cy.on('window:confirm',() => { true })

But instead, I'm getting what seems window alert but from cypress itself, and not the window document
[image]

Note that this window alert stop the code execution, and therefore, stopping the test until I click "ok"

How am I supposed to close this ? Because any solutions I've seen works for me :/